# Converting a .CR3 file to .JPG using canon_cr3 library in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, canon-sdk

I want to convert a .CR3 file (camera is a Canon PowerShot SX70 HS) to a .JPG file using Python. I found a project on GitHub which actually should do the desired task: https://github.com/lclevy/canon_cr3

I've installed the canon_cr3 library using the setup.py file. Indeed, the canon_cr3-13mar2019-py3.6.egg file exists after installing the library. Hence, when I type

```
from canon_cr3 import Image
```

in the Python 3.6.1 shell and press Enter, it seems that the import is successful (no error message arises). However, when I try the example on https://github.com/lclevy/canon_cr3#example-usage

```
image = 'D:\pic\test_img.CR3'
image = image.replace("\\", "/") #working on Windows
img = Image(image)
```

an error arises:

```
NameError: name 'getLongBE' is not defined
```

The error arises in the *'cr3_lib.py'* file executing the *stsz()* function. The *getLongBE()* function is defined in the library's *'parse_cr3.py'* file. However, I cannot see the link between the *'parse_cr3.py'* file and the *'cr3_lib.py'* file.

I don't know what I'm missing, what to try or how to resolve this issue. Do you have any suggestions?
Or is there another method to convert .CR3 files to .png in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Just add the missing function inside `cr3_lib.py` file:

```
def getLongBE(d, a):
    return unpack('>L',(d)[a:a+4])[0]
```

And your `cr3_lib.py` file should look like this:

```
from struct import unpack, Struct
from binascii import unhexlify, hexlify
# from parse_cr3 import getLongBE # remove this line

def getLongBE(d, a):
    return unpack('>L',(d)[a:a+4])[0]

...
```

**Note:** remove the following line from the current file if you added before:

```
from parse_cr3 import getLongBE
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal. I've entered the line in the _cr3_lib.py_ file. Indeed, this solves the error described above, but an `IndexError: list index out of range'` arises in the _parse_cr3.py_ file in the line `f = open(args[0], 'rb')`. Printing the `args` variable i get an empty array. I'm still investigating, why that is.

Comment: @BenjaminFischer, I updated my answer. I downloaded the [source code](https://github.com/lclevy/canon_cr3), and run it after modifying as shown in my answer. It worked for me. Hope my answer is helpful :)

Comment: Thank you! It works for me, too. Now I can use the canon_cr3 library to create the .jpg file. By the way, I realized that another option is to call the `self.get_long_be()` method instead of the `getLongBE()` function within the `stsz()` function, since the `self.get_long_be()` method is defined in the `cr3_lib.py` file. My next task is now to figure out how to get the uncompressed image information from the canon_cr3 Image object.

Comment: Great. Please upvote my answer if you found it useful 